# iOS Change pitch of voice while recording the sound file

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudiorecorder

My basic question is that , Is it possible that I can change pitch of the sound before recording so that the recorded sound shall be saved as my desired pitch value. Means If I need to record sound in low/high pitch what Audio settings I need to do before recording a sound.

Regards

Comment: there's no way to modify it _before_ recording

Comment: Can there be a way to do it through sample rates or other audio units ?